# Showing search button as submit button in mobile devices keyboards

Tags: android, html, mobile-safari

I want to show Search button in mobile devices keyboards when focusing on search input field in my HTML5 document :

[image: Search Button in android devices HTML5]

Comment: up vote and accept the answer if you have got yours.

Comment: I had up voted ! I usually wait for 2 hours :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **HTML5 type attribute** for `input` element in HTML page

For example.

```
<input id="mysearch" type="search" />
```

Comment: If anyone is using edittext than add `android:imeOptions="actionSearch"`